# name search with Full Text search

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

Table: User

```
...|Name                  |...|..
__________________________________
...|george walker          |...|..
...|...                   |...|..
```

Now I want to write a query to get the above record for the following inputs:
`george`
`george walker` 
`george walker bush` etc.

ie., alteast half of the words in search string should match but not any word match

How can I write a query for this?

Note: I would like to use `Full Text Search` feature because this table has few millions of records. 
I doubt if I could use `SOUNDEX` with `Full Text`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have full text indexed your Name column...

```
declare @search varchar(1000), @searchquery varchar(1000)

select @search = 'george walker bush' -- your search terms here.

select @search = ltrim(rtrim(@search))  
select @searchquery  = 'ISABOUT (' 
    + replace(@search, ' ', ' WEIGHT (0.4), ') 
    + ' WEIGHT (0.4))'

select * from [User]
inner join 
    Containstable(
        [User], 
        Name, 
        @searchquery
        ) as keys
        on keys.[key]    = [user].id
where rank>50
```